# SUM mixed with LEFT JOIN and GROUP BY in MYSQL query

Tags: mysql, group-by, sum, left-join

I am having some trouble with a query that involves sum, a left join and a group by

```
$sql = "
SELECT h.id AS hid
     , SUM(l.likes) AS likes 
  FROM homes h
  LEFT 
  JOIN likes l
    ON l.homeid = h.id
 GROUP 
    BY h.id
";
```

Instead of summing the likes for each home, it is giving NULL if the home has no likes or the number 8873 if it has one like.  I really can't understand the 8873.

Of note, there are a lot of likes in this table for other things in which case the value for l.homeid is NULL.  Could that be throwing things off?

**Edit:**

I added another like for a homeid from a different user and now it is giving me 8906 instead of 8873 for those with 1 like and 17812 for the one with two likes. This is very strange. The data type for all the numbers is int(11). I am going to create a totally new table and see if that one does the same thing. I'm also going to remove a unique index I added recently.

Comment: Please add sample data to your question.  The current behavior of your query sounds correct to me.

Comment: I'll try to reproduce the error with a new table. This one has a lot of legacy data in it.

Comment: Please in code questions give a [mre]--cut & paste & runnable code, including smallest representative example input as code; desired & actual output (including verbatim error messages); tags & versions; clear specification & explanation. Give the least code you can give that is code that you show is OK extended by code that you show is not OK. (Debugging fundamental.) For SQL that includes DBMS & DDL (including constraints & indexes) & input as code formatted as a table.When you get an unexpected result , isolate the first erroneous subexpression & its input & output. (Debugging fundamental.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try moving the aggregation into a derived table and joining then joining that:

```
SELECT
    h.id                   AS hid
  , COALESCE( l.likes, 0 ) AS likes
FROM homes h
LEFT JOIN (
        SELECT
            homeid
          , COUNT( likes ) AS likes
        FROM likes
        GROUP BY
            homeid
    ) AS l ON h.id = l.homeid
```

Also try `COUNT()` instead of `SUM()`